# Creating a mutli-step form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to figure out a good approach for the multi-step form I am doing but I can't really figure out a good solution for it. I have each class as sections identified as `name-section` and I have the classes stored in a array for the sections to add with the prefix `-section` as shown in html `<div class="rules-section">`. I'm trying to have it remove the current step and show the next step proceeding after clicking continue. If someone is able to give me some tips or examples on how I would do this it would be much appreciated.

```js
        function initalizeCreate() {
            //loadPalletes();
            sectionLoad();
            $(".rules-section").show();

            $(".btn").on("click", function() {
                $(".rules-section").remove();
                $(".color-section").fadeIn();
            });
            $(".username").keyup(function() {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    $(".penguinName").text("Penguin Name");
                } else {
                    $(".penguinName").text(this.value);
                }
            });
        }
        function sectionLoad() {
            for(let section in sections) {
               // console.log(sections[section])
                // $(sections[section] + "-section").show();
            }
        }
        function gotoSection(index) {
            $(sections[index] + "-section").show();
         
        }
        let sections = [".rules", ".color", ".info"];
     
        window.onload = function() {
            initalizeCreate();
        };
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <div class="rules-section">
                <div class="grid-rules">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <div id="rule-title">Respect other penguins</div>
                            CP does not tolerate any swearing, bullying or mean behavior toward other penguins. Disciplinary action will be taken should any one of these occur while playing.
                        </div>
                        <img id="rule-image" src="images/respect.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <div id="rule-title">No inappropriate talk</div>
                            References to drugs and alcohol related activities, and sexual, racial or otherwise inappropriate talk are not permitted.
                        </div>
                        <img id="rule-image" src="images/inapp.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <div id="rule-title">Never reveal personal information</div>
                            The best way to stay safe online is to NEVER share your real name, phone number, address, email or passwords.
                        </div>
                        <img id="rule-image" src="images/personal.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <div id="rule-title">No cheating</div>
                            Use of third party programs to cheat is prohibited. Players who use any third party programs while playing risk being permanently banned.
                        </div>
                        <img id="rule-image" src="images/cheating.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div id="agree"> <span class="toggle">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" /><label>I agree to the CP Rules.</label>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div id="terms"> <span class="toggle">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="terms" /><label>I agree to the <a id="hyper" href="#">Terms of Use</a></label>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <button class="btn" name="submit">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div class="color-section" style="display: none;">
                <div id="color-form">
                    <p id="epname">Enter Your Penguin Name:</p>
                    <input type="text" class="username" id="inputaligncenter" />
                    <div id="cpsmall">Minimum 4 characters: use only numbers, letters and spaces.</div>
                    <p id="cpname">Click on a Color:</p>
                    <div id="palletes"></div>
                    <img id="paintbucket" src="images/paintbucket.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="doll-container"> <img id="doll" src="images/doll.png" /> <span class="penguinName">Penguin Name</span> </div>
                <button class="btn" name="submit">Continue</button>
            </div>
            <div class="info-section" style="display: none;">
                <div id="info-form">
                    <div id="ppname-wrapper">
                        Penguin Password:
                        <div id="ppsmall">This is the password you will use to login to CP. </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                        <p id="activatedTxt">your penguin must be activated before you will be able to play at CP</p>
                        Parent's Email Address:
                        <div id="ppsmall">Please enter your parent's valid email address. CP will send your parent an e-mail with an activation code.</div>
                        <div class="env"> <img src="images/envelope.png">
                            <input type="email" name="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="doll-container fixed"> <img id="doll" src="images/doll.png" /> <span class="penguinName">Penguin Name</span> </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn" name="submit">Continue</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: There are some good simple examples you can plug and play with that might make this easier for you like:

[1] https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/nPOZZR

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp

[3] https://laratutorials.com/jquery-multi-step-form-wizard-plugin-with-validation/

Hope these help

Comment: I ended up figuring it out but thank you. I went with a different and simple approach then what I was originally doing.